# ASP.NET MVC Razor Syntax: Is it an issue for razor to interpret @if(@Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore, glass-mapper

I am checking logs of exception and I came across an exception in lazy loading with glass mapper. I have a sitecore project with mvc and one of the views (shared cshtml) contains the following loop:

```
@foreach(var item in @Model.Collection)...
```

I would usually write:

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.Collection)...
```

I tried googling, but I found nothing. I have inherited this code from another guy, who I cannot contact. The website actually loads the page with no error. I've tried the same loop in pure MVC and it loads the page with no Error. However, I get this lazy loading issue that the entity is null there in logs (sitecore).

I will know more tomorrow, but I am curious regarding this. Has anyone came across such issue?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it works because C# allows the @ character at the beggining of a variable name (or any identifier, as @recursive pointed out in a comment).
Actually this is used to allow having variable names that are also reserved words.
After escaping the foreach, the code executed will look like:

```
foreach(var item in @Model.Collection)
```

And this is valid code in C#

Comment: I would use that in the case to escape htmlAttributes as in:

`@Html.ActionLine("Details", "Details", "Home", null, new { @id = 1 })`

I haven't seen in in the foreach until now, though. Well, I guess the exception is due something else. However, the stack trace end with the foreach.

Comment: You can use @ as a prefix to any identifier in C#, not just variables.  And that's always true.  There's no exception.

Comment: The bug turned out to be something from another world. I was curious about the use of @ however. Thanks for help :)